# How can I run an AMP stack on Ubuntu for Android?

Tags: lamp

I want to get vtigerCRM running on an Android tablet, what needs to be done to make this possible?

First off is there an Apache/MySQL/PHP stack available?

If so what needs to be done to run a standard install of the vTigerCRM software?

All assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could buy ksweb on play store. It supports apache, mysql, and php. But you need to install [phpmyadmin [image: Install phpmyadmin]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/phpmyadmin) to create and use a database. You will have a 3 day trial of the full version (without any restrictions in functionality). If you love it, you can buy it through the option button.